# How to use the "editorconfig" in a .prettierrc in v3.0.3

Tags: prettier, editorconfig

I have prettier v3.0.3 and this `.prettierrc` config:

```
{
  "editorconfig": true,
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "css",
  "proseWrap": "preserve",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "semi": true,
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "singleAttributePerLine": true
}
```

But when I run "prettier:fix" I get this warning:
`[warn] Ignored unknown option { editorconfig: true }.`

Whats wrong here?
Also I wonder where prettier looks for the `.editorconfig` file. In the same folder where the .prettierrc is, or also in parent folders?

See: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/discussions/15603

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You cannot use the editorconfig option inside .prettierrc. Prettier use .editorconfig as the configuration file if .prettierrc does not exist and a .editorconfig file exists.

source @sosukesuzuki: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/discussions/15603#discussioncomment-7586261